# Initializing framebuffer device without udev

Tags: udev, sysvinit, yocto, framebuffer, drm

I am trying to reduce boot time in a Raspberry Pi 4 using Yocto Linux. The system uses SysV init. 
There is psplash that uses framebuffer, and Qt application that uses DRM/eglfs, displayed respectively.

I decided to launch udev after my application starts in order to save 1+ seconds. This does not affect my Qt application, since it uses DRM/eglfs. However, it affects psplash since udev somehow creates `/dev/fb0`. Here is an excerpt from dmesg regarding drm / fb:

```
[    8.825197] [drm] Initialized v3d 1.0.0 20180419 for fec00000.v3d on minor 0     
[    8.849067] initcall v3d_drm_register+0x0/0x1000 [v3d] returned 0 after 45382 use
cs                                                                                  
[    9.093550] calling  vc4_drm_register+0x0/0x1000 [vc4] @ 295                     
[    9.118718] vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound fe600000.firmwarekms (ops vc4_fkms_ops [vc4]) 
[    9.134170] [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for soc:gpu on minor 1          
[    9.146065] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).          
[    9.159925] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.                  
[    9.171742] [drm] Setting vblank_disable_immediate to false because get_vblank_ti
mestamp == NULL                                                                     
[    9.337974] vc4-drm soc:gpu: fb0: DRM emulated frame buffer device
```

I could not find a udev rule that handles framebuffer:

```
    root@raspberrypi4-64:/lib/udev/rules.d# grep -nir "drm"                             
    60-drm.rules:3:ACTION!="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", SUBSYSTEMS=="pci|usb|platform", I
    MPORT{builtin}="path_id"                                                            
    50-udev-default.rules:34:SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL!="renderD*", GROUP="video"        
    50-udev-default.rules:39:SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL=="renderD*", GROUP="video", MODE="
    0666" 
    root@raspberrypi4-64:/lib/udev/rules.d# grep -nir "fb"
```

In fact, `grep -nir "fb"` gives nothing.

I would like to identify how udev initializes framebuffer devices, and initialize it before psplash (by using stuff like tmpfs, mknod), without udev. I already tried doing `mknod /dev/fb0 c 29 0`, /dev/fb0 is created but nothing on the display. Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

**NOTE:** If anything is missing in the description, please let me know.